# How to set img attr with JS

Tags: javascript

So we have a page we with a lot image,they haven’t width and height attr, so my task will be set this attr for all images on page

const images = document.querySelectorAll(„img”)

And then with foreach i need to set attr

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: images.forEach(img => {

img.setAttributes(„width”, VALUE)

Comment: And i dont know what a value will be, i need to set value of img element itself

Comment: The quotes you're using look like syntax errors.  Aside from that, please update the question to include a [mcve] demonstrating the problem you've encountered.  Since the entirety of the functionality is HTML/CSS/JS, you can include a runnable Stack Snippet to observe what isn't working.

Comment: I just want to know how can i get width and height of img tag

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer can help your question

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

images.forEach((img) => {

   // to get attribute width & height of img 
   let img_width  = img.getAttribute('width');
   let img_height = img.getAttribute('height');

   // to set attribute width & height of img
   img.width  = '100px';
   img.height = '100px';

   // or to set attribute width & height you can set using style attribute
   img.style.width  = '100px';
   img.style.height = '100px';

})
```